# GIS implementation for map, direction and journey planner

Tags: dictionary, gis

I am planning to implement a web application for map, direction and journey planner. But I don't have any development experience in this area. So I would like to know how I can start off. What are the most suitable databases to store map data? Is there any api that I can make use of to provide direction or plan journey? Thanks in advance.

---

I think I have to modify question in order to provide more details. I have searched on Stack Exchange and found out a some other questions about GIS, and I have some basic idea on implementation. Now I would like to know if there is any recommended book that covers over all implementation of a web based GIS appliction.

I am a Java developer with a few years of experience. Given my background, what kind of technology/framework/GIS server should I considered for my implementation.

Regards,

K.Hein

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this Asp.net MVC tutorial, [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx). It is not a direction and journey planner, but an event planner with AJAX mapping support. You can take the mapping functionality and roll out your own app as per your requirements.